# How to add months to a date

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, date

I just want to share the answer to my question. This is the code:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim NextTime As Date = Now
    TextBox1.Text = NextTime.AddDays("set a count here".0) ' for example (100.0)
End Sub
```

This can be used for due dates or date counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim newDate As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(Label1.Text).AddMonths(6)

Duedate.text = newDate.ToString
```

You need to make sure the format is correct though, this can be done with the following bit of code:

```
Dim pattern As String = "MM-dd-yy" 
Dim parsedDate As Date 

   If DateTime.TryParseExact(Label1.Text, pattern, Nothing, 
                             DateTimeStyles.None, parsedDate) Then
      Console.WriteLine("We're good!)
   Else
      Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert")
   End If
```